# Pandas query group by /order by

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get the following using Pandas query.

```
SELECT site_id, count(issue) FROM [Randall]
where site_id >3
group by site_id 
LIMIT 10
```

My query could be found below; However, when executed it have 2 'issue' columns, one for the actual issue and another the 'count' and I have repetitive issues. what I want is to sum the issues by site.

```
w_alarms.groupby(['site_id', 'issue']).size()
```

Comment: Provide sample df

Comment: @RahulAgarwal all data are all strings. Nothing is number.

Comment: please provide a [minimal,complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethink like

```
w_alarms[w_alarms.site_id > 3].groupby('site_id')['issue'].count()
```

Comment: So you need to preprocess your dataset. Maybe you can solve it by doing `w_alarms[w_alarms.site_id.astype(int) > 3].groupby('site_id')['issue'].count()` but you should really construct a proper dataset first and not on the fly.

Comment: I just figured it out myself  this one.  Do you have any idea of how you actually order the issue by desc? its been giving me headaches for the last 30mn

Comment: `df.sort_values(by='issue', ascending=False)`. You should really take a look at pandas doc https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
w_alarms.siteid[w_alarms.siteid>3].value_counts().head(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide example of output you desired.
You might want this:

```
w_alarms.issue.groupby[w_alarms.siteid[w_alarms.siteid > 3]].count()
```

Comment: If column `siteid ` is string, then you might convert it to numeric. `pd.to_numeric(w_alarms.siteid)`. And if you want to limit the output then call `head(10)` after `count()`